# lambda function -Unable to import module 'lambda': Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I use win 10 and subsystem Ubuntu 20.04.6, python 3.9, use package like boto3, pymysql and pandas. I pack all my extension into a zip file and then upload this zip file to my s3 buckets, and then create a lambda function and upload from S3. I run a test in AWS console and get error as below:

[image]

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda': Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.9"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.24.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Please help me how to solve this issue. thanks

I try using pip3 install numpy --upgrade and not working at all.

Comment: Containers lambda functions are much better for dealing with dependencies. Why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following :

1. Go to pypi.org
2. Download the following:

   - pandas-1.4.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
   - numpy-1.23.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
   - pytz-2022.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
3. Run `pip install wheel`
4. Go to the folder where you downloaded the .whl files and run `wheel unpack filename.whl` (replace filename) for each library.
5. You have 2 options now :

   - You can now create a layer with all these libraries by copying the unwheeled folders to an empty folder named *python* and then zip it and create an AWS Lambda Layer and reference this layer in your AWS Lambda Function.
     The advantage here is that you can reuse this layer with any other Lambda function you will create.

   or

   - Copy the packages to folder where you have the lambda handler function (you can skip the dist-info folders)

Good luck.